# how to convert mjpeg to h264 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mjpeg encoded video with this metadata:

```
{ filename: './public/uploads/f8cca1dfff2558e22d83c1b1c7766d0d.mov',
  title: '',
  artist: '',
  album: '',
  track: '',
  date: '',
  synched: true,
  duration: { raw: '00:00:06.01', seconds: 6 },
  video:
   { container: 'mov',
     bitrate: 858336,
     stream: 0,
     codec: 'mjpeg',
     resolution: { w: 4096, h: 2160 },
     resolutionSquare: { w: 4096, h: 2160 },
     aspect: { x: 256, y: 135, string: '256:135', value: 1.8962962962962964 },
     rotate: 0,
     fps: 23.98,
     pixelString: '72:72',
     pixel: 1 },
  audio:
   { codec: 'pcm_s16le',
     bitrate: '1536',
     sample_rate: 48000,
     stream: 0,
     channels: { raw: 'stereo', value: 2 } } }
```

I wanna convert it to h264 encoded in a mp4 container using the following command:

```
 ffmpeg -i,./public/uploads/f8cca1dfff2558e22d83c1b1c7766d0d.mov,-strict -2 -f mp4 -vcodec h264,./public/uploads/result.mp4
```

Conversion is executed without any errors however the resulting file's metadata still indicates the container is mov and the file is not playing

Comment: there are some unneeded comments in your command line, try this:
`ffmpeg -i ./public/uploads/f8cca1dfff2558e22d83c1b1c7766d0d.mov -strict -2 -f mp4 -vcodec h264 ./public/uploads/result.mp4`
and then `ffprobe -i ./public/uploads/result.mp4`